# Lightning arrestor for a building with VHF antenna without disrupting wireless signals

Tags: antenna, surge-protection, lightning, vhf

Lightning protection is to be provided for a building where already VHF antenna is available. An omnidirectional ground plane antenna is used for VHF. The height of the Franklin rod provided as Class A protection is such that the tallest point is at a height less than the VHF antenna.

Concerns have been raised that the efficacy of the lightning/surge protection will be compromised. At the same time concerns have been raised about improper signal reception in case the lightning arrestor height is increased.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a solution to this problem?

No. You have no option other than to necessarily locate the vertical ground plane antenna within the cone of protection of the lightning rod defined by the ['Protective Angle Method'](https://axis-india.com/protective-angle-method-for-lightning/) according to IEC 62305.

[image]

The protective angle 'α' depends on the Class of LPS and the height of the lightning rod.

The angle is determined from Table 2 in IEC 62305-3.

For simplicity’s sake, the table below shows the protective angle for lightning rods that are up to 2m in length.

[image]

A more comprehensive guide for different heights of the lightning rod and the corresponding protective angles 'α' may also be accessed via the above link.

Comment: I'd like to voice my approval of this answer. Well done. And to the OP: yes, a lightning rod located at some distance from your vertical omni antenna will act as a reflector, in a narrowish angle of directions = will create a null in the directional diagram :-(

Comment: @frr - Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use an antenna surge protector to connect the antenna to <strike>the lightning ground</strike>  safety ground

If lightning strikes the antenna  it's toast but the surge will go into the  ground system.

See frr's page linked in the comment.

Comment: Hmm. My mouse pointer is attracted to the downvote button, but ultimately I prefer positive approach and explanation. In general, during a storm, the outside lightning downconductor is considered "hot", therefore specifically signal wiring that is to enter the building must *not* get earthed to the outside lightning downconductor. What actually matters is the distance from the nearest common ground, linking indoor PE and outdoor LPS. I have [scribbled something](http://support.fccps.cz/industry/62305/62305.html) on this very topic.

Comment: You leave me with a dilemma, delete this answer and thus hide your comment, or keep it live.  I have opted for a minor edit.